# Само-удаление после использования программы

Tags: c#

Запускаю .exe файл и он должен удалиться после использования, использую `ProcessStartInfo`. Есть ли ещё способы убить файл после  использования?

```
public static void Active()
{
    ProcessStartInfo Flash = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Flash.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + 
 (new FileInfo((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath)).Name +"\"";
    Flash.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; Flash.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Flash.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    Process.Start(Flash).Dispose();
 // Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

**UPD**

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
 Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + 
 (new FileInfo((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath)).Name + "\"",
 WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
 CreateNoWindow = true,
 FileName = "cmd.exe"
});
```

Решил сделать так, после окончания работы программы считает 3 секунды и программа самоудаляется.

Comment: Причем тут обычный файл и `Process.Kill()` или я не понимаю чего-то? Для удаления файла используйте метод `File.Delete() `.

Comment: @sp7, .exe -шный файл который я запустил, он же и должен удалиться., `File.Delete()` для другого файла. Обновил пост, думаю так понятнее будет)

Comment: @ArteS файл-исполнитель не может удалять сам себя. Для этого должен существовать другой процесс, который сможет это сделать при условии, что программа закрыта. Например, Вы можете сделать батник, который сможет удалить как саму программу, так и себя после выполнения операции.

Comment: @ArteS в вашей программе вы можете сгенерировать `.bat` файл, который удалит `.exe` после завершения.

Comment: @sp7, наверное так и сделаю, а чем хуже 2-й вариант ? Интересно узнать почему не стоит использовать такой метод использования?!